# Why doesn't Major compaction free space but garbagecollect does?

Tags: cassandra, tombstone

We have a three node Cassandra cluster with RF 3. There is a table with SizeTieredCompaction strategy. In some cases, performing a major compaction `nodetool compact --split-output -- <keyspace> <table>` on this table, doesn't free up disk, but performing `nodetool garbagecollect -- <keyspace> <table>` frees up the disk. The gc_grace_seconds is set to 1 hour and default_time_to_live is set to 3 hours:

‍‍

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace.table (
    id text PRIMARY KEY,
    json text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 10800
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 3600
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Does anyone know the reason?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Nodetool garbagecollect** performs single sstable compaction, so it can shrink the size of individual files on disk.  Garbagecollect has been available available since Cassandra 2.10 and removes deleted partitions and rows by default. If you specify *-g cell* it will also remove overwritten or deleted cells.

**Nodetool compact** Compaction combines several (typically four) smaller sstables together while also cleaning-up overwritten and expired data.  Size-tiered compaction requires *min_threshold* tables to combine.

Compaction may also look at an estimate of number of droppable tombstones in a sstable, and compact a single table if the ratio is above the *tombstone_threshold* (0.2 or 20% by default)

The documentation on compact states:

> ...triggers a minor compaction when there are a number of similar sized SSTables on disk as configured by the table subproperty, min_threshold.

[DSE 6.7 nodetool compact](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/tools/nodetool/toolsCompact.html?hl=nodetool%2Ccompact)

Thus garbagecollect will always run, but compact will ignore a table if min_threshold (default 4) isn't satisfied and the droppable tombstone ratio is not very high.  Also, garbagecollect requires less free disk space to run.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  it was to be expected that garbagecollect freed disk space. but i also expected that a major compaction combines all sstables together and new sstable doesn't have any additional data (basically the goal of compaction is delete tombstones (after gc period)). Actually why didn't major compaction free up the disk? is it related to overlapping sstables? when something can be deleted with gc it can be deleted with major compaction too? isn't right?

Comment: Assume you have many overwritten data rows, but you have only 2 sstables on disk, you could recover space with garbagecollect, but compact wouldn't run if min_threshold  = 4 (default for STCS).  Also, the tables have to be 'similarly sized' for compaction to combine them.  The point to keep in mind is that size-tired compaction is designed not just to recover space, but to combine tables into 4X larger tables.

Comment: it's not true. i tested some cases and realized that there was no need for 4 sstables (min_threshold) when you perform major compaction (nodetool compact). This restriction only applies to minor comaction.

Comment: @MostafaBayat I looked at the code, and you are right, there is another twist.  The STCS comment in the code explains it as: "if there is no sstable to compact in standard way, try compacting a single sstable whose droppable tombstone ratio is greater than threshold [default 0.2]".  https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/db/compaction/SizeTieredCompactionStrategy.java